# Delphi - Creating a visual component & assigning event to it

Tags: delphi

How i can create a visual component at runtime and assign event to it in a unit.

I try with the following code but its shows

> method pointer and regular procedure

```
unit uName;

interface

Uses
  ....
  SHDocVw;

implementation

procedure DocComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  //DoSomething
end;

procedure CreateWB;
var
  wb: TWebBrowser;
Begin
  wb := TWebBrowser.Create(bgPnl);
  with wb do
  .....
  wb.OnDocumentComplete  := DocComplete; // Error line > E2009 Incompatible types
End;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Delphi is an object oriented language, yet the code above is procedural. Not that you're not allowed to, but it defeats the whole purpose of using Delphi.

Comment: @Jerry There are plenty of scenarios where unit scope functions are a sound choice

Comment: @David Yes indeed, but for a web browser?

Comment: Why not? If I want to square a number I write `Sqr(x)`. Why is that bad?

Comment: Obviously that's fine, I'm not talking about that though. I'm wondering how OP intends to use the `wb` variable further. It's in its own procedure called `CreateWB` which I assume means this is one of many procedures, this one dedicated to creating it. But it's a local variable and doesn't appear to expose that variable anywhere else. I'm just concerned with OP's particular choice for this particular scenario - it's not natural.

Comment: @Jerry Perhaps you needed to clarify the original comment. As I read it you were saying the OOP code should always be used, procedural never.

Comment: @David my original comment explicitly says "Not that you're not allowed to". It was just a reminder that the whole purpose of using an Object Oriented language is to take advantage of creating self-contained object structures.

Comment: @Jerry Not really. The point is to use the right tool for the right job. OOP is not always the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your own event into a form Class or other class in your project (in the private block or public as you want)

```
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DocCopmlete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
  public
```

then you can assign the WebBrowser event to the new one

```
wb.OnDocumentComplete := yourClass.DocCopmlete;
```

So you could use a class instead of a unit like yours (unit uName)

Comment: Actually this isn't the full story. You don't need an instance. A class method of a record or a class will suffice. And is probably a better fit here.